# C# Winform Desktop icon refuse to change on a particular computer

Tags: c#, winforms, favicon

I am trying to change my application's icon.

1) I have changed the icon on the form by going to form-->properties-->Icon

2) I have also changed the Icon on the project by going to Project--> properties--> Application-->Icon and Manifest.

But my Icon  still didn't change, I have restarted my computer but no success. I finally used another computer and the new icon appear. So my question is does anyone know whats happening?

Comment: Any difference in the OS of those two computers?

Comment: They are both windows. Actually the new computer is a virtual machine on the same desktop.

Comment: And the version of windows? Anything I can come up with is the path to the icon..

Comment: Thank you, the main computer is Win7 and the new virtual M/c is Xp.
By the way, the new icon appear everywhere except on the desktop shortcut. It appears on the start menu fine and even the .exe file

Comment: @electricalbah I had the same issue on my computer. I believe it's caused by the icon cache in Windows. What I usely do is removing the icon, cleaning up the PC (with CCleaner), then, add the icon. Or you can just delete `/Documents and Settings/Username/Local Settings/Application Data/IconCache.db` (Windows XP) or `/Documents and Settings/Username/AppData/Local/IconCache.db` (Windows 7)

Comment: @CédricBignon Thanks very much, it worked like magic. I ended up deleting the IconCache.db file.   How can I mark this as answer, might be useful for someone in the future. I wasted the whole day trying to resolve this issue

Comment: @electricalbah I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue on my computer. I believe it's caused by the icon cache in Windows.

What I usely do is removing the icon, cleaning up the PC (with *CCleaner*), then, add the icon.

Or you can just delete `/Documents and Settings/<username>/Local Settings/Application Data/IconCache.db` (*Windows XP*) or `/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/IconCache.db` (*Windows 7*).